# How to select from option menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, select-menu

I need to be able to change certain option from select menu to be as default (start) value when I do something.

For example when I declare it, English language is default value.

How to change that with the code and not with the click.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<select name="websites1" id="websites1" style="width:120px" tabindex="1">
    <option value="english" selected="selected"  title="images/us.gif">English</option>
    <option value="espanol" title="images/es.gif">Espanol</option>
    <option value="italian" title="images/it.gif">Italiano</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In the body tag I have declared:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body select").msDropDown();
});
</script>
```

I am using this [SCRIPT](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

I have tried all of the bellow examples and none this is good for me.

What else can I do change default select value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is working for me as mentioned in the docs:

```
$('#websites1').msDropDown().data('dd').set('selectedIndex',2);
```

This will select *italian* ;)

/edit:

Keep in mind that @Patrick M has a more advanced approach and he posted his approach before I posted mine ;)

If you are having weird css issues like I did, try this undocumented stuff:

```
$('#websites1_msa_2').click(); // this will also select the italian
```

As you can see the id is generated by $('#**websites1**_msa_2') the id of the selectbox plus the $('#websites1_msa_**2**') index of the option item.

A bit hacky but works ;)

So you could then define a JavaScript-Function like  this:

```
var jQueryImageDD_selectByName = function(name) {
  var children = $('#websites2_child').children();
  for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
    var label = children[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
    if(label === name) {
      children[i].click()
    }
  }
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
jQueryImageDD_selectByName('Italiano'); // will select Italiano :)
```

Comment: Useful answer. Thanks. Had trouble figuring out how to access the msDropDown object.

Answer (score 2):

He does say

> You can set almost all properties via object

So, just guessing from the documentation examples he provides on that page... I would think adapting this:

```
var oHandler = $('#comboboxid').msDropDown().data("dd");
oHandler.size([true|false]);
//Set or get  the size property
```

To the `.value` property might work. So for you to set the language to Italian, try

```
var oHandler = $('#comboboxid').msDropDown().data("dd");
oHandler.value('italian');

// Or maybe the way to do it is this:
oHandler.set('value', 'italian');
// Or maybe 'value' shouldn't be in single quotes
//set property
```

If that doesn't work, you could try looping over all the properties, getting and comparing the value at each index and, when you find it, setting the selected index to that property name.

```
var languageSelect = $('websites1');
var oHandler = $('#websites1').msDropDown().data("dd");
for(var index = 0; index < languageSelect.length; index++) {
    var option = oHandler.item([index]);
    if(option == 'italian') {
        oHandler.set("selectedIndex", index);
        break;
    }
}
```

One of those should work. If not, you're pretty much just going to have to wait for a reply from the author.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `selectedIndex` to change the index of the selected option (0 being the first)

```
document.getElementById("websites1").selectedIndex = 1; //espanol
```

, or you can use `value` to change the text of the value (and if there's a match, it will change it automatically).

```
document.getElementById("websites1").value = 'espanol';
```

Comment: I have tried the second example but it is not working for me. I am using this script LINK:http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

use `selectedIndex`. See [this page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml). A select control has an `options` property, which basically is an array of option elements. The first element in your select is options[0], english, so:

```
document.getElementById("websites1").selectedIndex = 0; //=> english
```

You can also make the first option selected by default using:

```
document.getElementById("websites1").options[0]
       .defaultSelected = true; //=> english by default
```

Comment: none of this is working for me. I am using this script : http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

working option (1. destroy msdropdown, 2. select by value, 3. set up msdropdown)

put this code somewhere in js:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    setValue: function(value) {
    var dd = $(this).msDropdown().data("dd");
    dd.destroy();
    $(this).val(value);
    $(this).msDropdown();
  }
});
```

setting value:

```
$('#selectorOfmsDropDown').setValue('opt10');
```

or just:

```
$("#selector").msDropdown().data("dd").setIndexByValue(newvalue);
```